# Least Euler-Jacobi Pseudoprime to several bases?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I'm aware that it is know what the smallest Strong pseudoprime to the first few primes is, and that the smallest strong pseudoprime to bases 2,3,5,7, and 11 is greater than 25,000,000,000. Is a similar result known for Euler pseudoprimes?

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulersche_Pseudoprimzahl  shows the first absolute Euler-pseudoprimes (numbers that are pseudoprime to every base coprime to the number). Since $$46657=13\cdot 37\cdot 97$$ is such an absolute euler-pseudoprime , the smallest example is at most $46657$, so far smaller than in the case of strong fermat-pseudoprimes.

Comment: @I believe this is a confusion of definition, sorry. By Euler test I am referring to the Euler-Jacobi test where you compare the residue against the Jacobi Symbol. With this definition, I am aware that there are no absolute Euler pseudoprimes

Comment: According to my calculations, the smallest such number is $$399\ 001$$

Comment: If we take the primes upto $p=31$ for checking, the smallest (and upto $10^8$ only) pseudoprime is $$14\ 469\ 841$$

Comment: If we also include $p=37$, the smallest pseudoprime is apparently exceeding $10^9$. I did not find an example yet.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://oeis.org/A354692

Here are several large upper-bounds:

```
a(46) <= 105216055594390884840438324972769319399722594046651360392070071794973423530188471087867855419188813164954561140227145977855514336985746250989366318940490798583710597151720075427387437940535767395296272532149397065590267303873620351321073058502920032770522836726669005262088263964215455869031740912313201227043
a(62) <= 2887148238050771212671429597130393991977609459279722700926516024197432303799152733116328983144639225941977803110929349655578418949441740933805615113979999421542416933972905423711002751042080134966731755152859226962916775325475044445856101949404200039904432116776619949629539250452698719329070373564032273701278453899126120309244841494728976885406024976768122077071687938121709811322297802059565867
a(100) <= 4755444900898962640570805079622407945513196432011911985648410022240088808985889200376095787527901239245756068158548164080646419498193938363223751878040975178651652955930683319090515589565114950046340315137578332784425652394857192999191244130079906060771897042318182261565231930157836276911534989784532752912947610193310744025493450293981924804993015182502555790249587996752315485361179895260300891395439822476185769523434215286135938029039660904526961670815522767096127450386003813203809365323894442795443565820952283705939380656438309180252554808691019535681908983623214664516034111470695703020642485875959651583213619466594932918476670651633816994599772548478768526764012575954414322984173288627
a(168) <= 6941543021392713730431668387068999032987505813628626223678951265009922979171494889619620919629218172938050022712650390231108995307237169269667644098333312684776469399924110119789527532161256933656112818109620945798457804143586629828296071826627003328849527952336389650813108369731049080747183836913592892951933560765345204468790419691959105305515726737868378312872715843312320064073674571001295106119373097331445689095722655847864191050899780290639922180983329597857624757187701943317347314318342630851888782724340309365489828447876503970224596096163190175586664838655752084811432643865453475409306234610422754846201955355349982116992680801631254169733179214516679698471486732095757632702985749004267668618407596194879010235811205069773345370151540294560707067912911972617117872568917574563797510424723636252899372760040898527772334935423922327351299656281932266256675132502702322760435460536571309302586539469310861406622510368133332971804029286468542260235396204271045794929827474636467550655521103657096119618759746982193439030809406498947869770588717242290031299573971411197982166717351757954266001066384132372994264058429334563291496657469558139808375030168417007373133166391119553220773091860698215980720042621281779381114805103592526045494482900527480395872621990534353634675251867
a(256) <= 106345207806296484231668043910066785399795652556314098984703724996175611913155370425059004666755351126370765757325069220154090475525113111331534155822504132427954121926028977897326016452032633264303162177531381326310998970713694521304856783427108211035837719173191888424497687716945903847840832601158220338315116311569353516661115745397618364437941836386218808101529448483687495168944238726821330736995943973596941803495501200742109710969089802656966120128959989924056907838239415947883597253487288911265130861076995785143322559232949628580082040985968381890859811544811963250166807225739883175758540592938038640525057077635260377283817570121188506720763322577723854603213904763949026451035886610117960695498777558294914095190286423434103595325322044355050505888390419892966130432853384420025991603809604285550077998959033403957562518661694503445321270371924756278334786001733438835926798599715925477942244937628383988529536076933049398733022131632892984494328799535905089231306547424707999668050846457897292105617153237859066140231207977706483096753560267776977308513770417672719215980272226316038096369457350381579229798547106736019854318870385754141371733858517502044218801634760265587498814280073328060552232702804872921969797735332629722017664747892121030708748712733180842486503682755515481434761547891191431690407378061063299887695616928512486921716155822944378708863947668462062195571745339003058779915940858554595239390172360173769656161537253021381577803596097455028941144286297184282046724577533468348343936096263977229393852616124982192888432604948830175933041671162863393593616389115022094081675889914163162852300506873558662214056728175728839204797446701664449699367321558065141345504373533192399722226922311408612622529245371708935701643178960931071329253928802738471610262504489056899252740549408250528391001108587552456472577625704595893048563596869581967781113019047808212452621728173827862405874506295664794063113108306419852891590636875366731732762664553725634243782507523770949879136684328870372364698244368287699980886402179469945231457642085062803806579094674257318340352731256782194724089323
```